# Using CSS Mixins in Polymer

Tags: css, polymer

I am working on a project that uses [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/). One component that is unclear to me is how to use the [style mixins](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-styles). For example, I have something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="bower/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="import" href="bower/polymer/polymer.html">     
    <link rel="import" href="bower/paper-styles/paper-styles.html">

  </head>

  <body unresolved class="fullbleed">
    <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
      <paper-material>
        <paper-item>
          <span class="paper-font-title">Welcome</span>
          <span class="flex"></span>
          <div class="secondary">
            Today Is: <span>[[ date ]]</span>
          </div>
        </paper-item>                                                                   
      </paper-material>
    </template>
  </body>
</html>
```

Basically, I'm trying to use the paper-font-title and secondary [typography styles](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-styles?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-styles). For some reason though, its like the styles aren't loaded. I looked in the console and I am not getting any 404s. For that reason, I assume the paper styles are being loaded. Why can't I use them?

Comment: What doesn't work? The `fullbleed` and `flex` classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use style mixins add a `<style is="custom-style"></style>` to your body.

As content of the style tag add CSS rules like

```
some-selector {
  @apply(--some-mixin-name);
}
```

Comment: I'm confused... I can't just import the styles in? If I'm understanding you correctly, I have to import the paper-styles. Then, I have to write wrapper rules for each style to apply the mixins? This seems odd.

Comment: You were talking about mixins in your question. Mixins and variables need to be applied, it's not enough to import them. There are also styles included where importing is enough, but they consist of selectors with attributes and values and they are applied by adding classes or attributes to elements. Just check the contents of the imported styles.

Comment: If you want to use paper styles as classes, use `<link rel="import" href="bower/paper-styles/paper-styles-classes.html">`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explanation on how to use the mixins: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#custom-style

I found it very helpful.